# Tiny MCE content formatting is not putting styles into the spans it creates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE Version 4.3.12 to edit html for an intranet Knowledge Base. When I try to change formatting on some of the text, i.e. changing font size with the font size dropdown, the editor shows the text as it should be. However, after posting, the output only shows the span tags that the styling should be in, with no styling in these tags. Even the view source option in the editor is showing span tags around the text with no styling at all. Is there any way to correct this?

EDIT: here is the code that calls TinyMCE. There is no special code being used to convert the output. The code within the editor is showing span tags around text, but no styling in these span tags.

```
    $('#editmodal-diag-text').tinymce({
                                    selector: "textarea"
                                    , content_css: 'style.css'
                                    , theme: "modern"
                                    , visual: false
                                    , selector: "textarea:not(.discussionPostBox)"
                                    , plugins: [
                                        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak adjustlineheight",
                                        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
                                        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
                                        "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern toggleparent frameset"
                                    ]
                                    , toolbar1: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline strikethrough | link image | alignleft aligncenter alignright | anchor link | lineheight"
                                    , toolbar2: " bullist numlist outdent indent | preview html | forecolor backcolor | removeformat | toggleparent | fontsizeselect | frameset | adjustlineheight"
                                    , inline_styles: true
                                    , verify_html: false
                                    , fix_list_elements: true
                                    , valid_styles: {
                                        '*': '*'
                                    }
                                    , valid_elements: '*[*]'
                                    , forced_root_block: false
                                    }

                                });
```

Comment: And where is the relevant code....

Comment: I suspect that your knowledge base software is responsible for this issue - if  TinyMCE has the code in it prior to save but its gone afterwards that is most likely something in your knowledge base's code.  As the other commenter stated without seeing this in action all you will get from SO are guesses.

Comment: No special code is being used in this case. The source code inside the editor shows span tags, but they're just generic tags. Only <span>text here</span>

Comment: Also, the knowledge base software is what we're developing in-house. It just takes the output from tiny, just what it is getting from the source code from the editor, and saves it to a database. It is doing this with no problem, and doing page edits outside of tinyMCE is having no trouble with saving what we want. Trouble is, most of the people using the knowledge base will not be coders, so they need to be able to use tinyMCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `valid_styles` in your configuration is what is causing your issues.  Please see this TinyMCE Fiddle:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/q2faab/1

If you just comment out your `valid_styles` portion of the configuration things seem to work.

I would note that a few plugins you have in your configuration (`adjustlineheight`, `toggleparent`, and `frameset`) don't seem to be part of standard TinyMCE so they are not part of the fiddle.  If things work in the fiddle but not with those plugins loaded its possible they could be causing an issue as well.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of that.